# How can I make this div appear inline next to the "Login" button?

Tags: html, css

I'm not sure how exactly I can make this `"Live Chat - Online" button` appear inline next to the `"Login" button.`

I've tried a few methods like using inline-block display, floating, etc. but I honestly feel like the issue is that I can't embed the `parature div id` inside the `<form action ="/webapps/login">` form tag. Being outside of the tag makes this a positional nightmare.

Problem is this page doesn't actually allow me to directly insert my `parature div id` in it because some of the page is constructed from dynamic javascript on the fly that I don't have access to. Is there a proper way to align the `Login` button with `Live Chat - Online` horizontally? Ignore the blurry text I am going to fix it later.

site: https://com-bb-dev.com.edu/

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
#loginBox{
    position: relative;
}
#parature {
    border-radius: 3px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 220px;
}
```